# How can i change text avatars colors in random

Tags: android

i want to add random colors to the text avatars in place of a single blue color
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cFYX.png)

my list code is this

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i =0;i<data.length();i++){
                        ModelFriendList temp = new ModelFriendList();
                        temp.setName(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                        temp.setUsername(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("phone"));
                        temp.setID(data.getJSONObject(i).getInt("UID"));
                        list.add(temp);
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add getter setter method of RandomColor in your model and add below code and in your item set background color from your model.

```
for(int i =0;i<data.length();i++){
               Random rnd = new Random(); 
               int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)); 
               ModelFriendList temp = new ModelFriendList();
               temp.setName(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
               temp.setUsername(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("phone"));
               temp.setID(data.getJSONObject(i).getInt("UID"));
               temp.setRandomColor(color);
               list.add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get random color by using **Random** class

```
    Random random = new Random(); 
    int color = Color.argb(255, random .nextInt(256), random .nextInt(256), random .nextInt(256));
```

After that you can set these color inside your model and get it when you want to set it on the view i.e avatar.